# An inequality for symmetric polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x_i$ be positive numbers where $1\leq i \leq n$ and $S_a = \displaystyle \sum _{\vert I \vert =a} x_{i^1} x_{i^2} \ldots x_{i^a}$. Is the following true ? If so, is it "obvious" in a sense ?
$S_{a+1} (a+1) \leq \frac{(n-a)S_1 S_a}{n}$

Comment: It is not obvious (at least to me) but it is true by [Newton's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities), your $S_a$ is the $\sigma_a$ in the wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that $S_1S_a$ has all the terms of $S_{a+1}$ and also many other superfluous terms with double contributions from one of the $a_i$ values. So at the very least, $S_{a+1} \leq S_1 S_a$ is obvious.

Then looking at the repeated terms, for each $k$, $\frac{a}{n}$ of the terms in $S_a$ involve $a_k$ and $\frac{n-a}{n}$ do not. And we know that $a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$, so it seems reasonable, if not exactly obvious, that these "repeated term" values are likely to be bigger, in aggregate, than the cross-product terms. So there is a certain intuition to $S_{a+1} \leq \frac{n-a}{n}S_1 S_a$.

As mentioned by [@achillehui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui), [Newton's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities) give the truth of the inequality.